# Python Group by two columns and then get the earliest and latest date

Tags: python, group-by, aggregation

When I was trying to get the earliest and latest date after groupby, I found that max results will be attached after min:

```
ATR_table.groupby(['USAGEID', 'STAT']).agg({'DATADTTM':'min','DATADTTM':'max'})
```

| USAGEID | STAT | DATADTTM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10140 | 0 | 2020-01-01 |
| 10140 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 10141 | 0 | 2020-01-01 |
| 10141 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 10140 | 0 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10140 | 1 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10141 | 0 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10141 | 1 | 2020-07-18 |

Is there a way that I can have the following result by using groupby?

| USAGEID | STAT | DATADTTM Min | DATADTTM Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10140 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10140 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10141 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-18 |
| 10141 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other columns, you could simply pass a plain list:

```
ATR_table.groupby(['USAGEID', 'STAT']).agg(['min', 'max'])
```

If you want to be able to use other functions on other columns, you should include a list in the dictionary:

```
ATR_table.groupby(['USAGEID', 'STAT']).agg({'DATADTTM':['min', 'max']})
```